# Update date in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, adminlte

I am using fullcalendar and it's so amazing so far I set almost everything like dragging external events from outside the calendar and then save it to my database by using

```
drop: function (date, allDay)
```

and resizing the date of events by using:

```
eventResize: function (event, delta)
```

And the delete using:

```
eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent){
if (jsEvent.pageX >= x1 && jsEvent.pageX <= x2 &&
                        jsEvent.pageY >= y1 && jsEvent.pageY <= y2) {
                        alert('deleteeee');

                        deletefromDb(event);
                    } 
}
```

**ONE THING LEFT IS THE UPDATE EVENT** and by that I mean when I want to change event date (not resizing) 
Does anyone know how can I do that ???

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop will trigger when you move an event from one time to another (i.e. you drag the whole event to change both start and end time, as opposed to resizing where you only change the end time)/

Comment: @ADyson yeah that's right thank you but I have problem when I print the event object it shows me the old start and not the new one after the drop, do you what can I do ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how/when you're printing that data. According to the docs the event passed to the eventDrop callback should have the new times in its start/end properties. If you've got a problem you'd have to edit the question to show an example of some code which reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend that you do it that way because generally the coordinates change in different devices.
For my part I leave the best option from my point of view:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {


                console.log(event.id + "Delete");


            },
```